# imagefill() turns rest of the area black

Tags: php, image

I'm using imagefill() for changing the background color if an image.But while doing so the other areas which are not to be affected, change its color to black.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("sample.png");
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0,0);
imagefill($image, 0,0, $background);
header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image,"sample.png");
```

This is my code.Can anyone tell me how this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the blending mode and saving the alpha

```
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code [ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php)

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $color );
```